# AMP web development amp-list won't highlight selected option

Tags: amp-html

Please assist me. I am trying to make an AMP dropdown list that opens another list when selected. However, I don't know how to set the css on the outer list button to look active(selected). I don't know how to dynamically add the css to the button on the outer list.

It looks like this:

[Image of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IZSE.png)

and the code I have is this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡ lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>amp-list</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!-- Import the `amp-list` component ... -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
  <!-- ... and the `amp-mustache` component in the header. -->
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
  <!-- Import the `amp-bind` component for dynamically changing the content of an `amp-list`. -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-list/index.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style amp-custom>
    * {
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #00438e;
      hyphens: auto;
    }

    div {
      color: #000;
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 1.6;
    }

    .title {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .mb10 {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .p_widget {
      margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .mt0 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .widget_tabs {
      width: 310px;
      border: 2px solid #e8f2fc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .tabs {
      background: #e8f2fc;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }

    .tab {
      color: hsl(212, 100%, 28%);
      padding: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .tab_active {
      background: #2578bb;
      padding: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .tab_active::before {
      content: '\25BE ';
    }

    .active {
      background: #2578bb;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    }

    .tab_contents {
      padding: 5px;
    }

   .tab::before {
      content: '\25B8 ';
    }

    .favicon {
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 0;
    }

    .shop {
      display: block;
      padding: 3px 5px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      width: 290px;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

    .price {
      width: 90px;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: right;
      position: absolute;
      top: 3px;
      left: auto;
      right: 5px;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .price::before {
      content: "";
    }

    .table {
      display: table;
    }

    .cell {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    .amazon_bar {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height: 25px;
      background: url(//i.wfcdn.de/5/amazon_bar_sprite_2.png) 0 -50px repeat-x;
      margin: 3px 0 0;
      padding: 0 5px 0 25px;
      font-size: 13px;
      width: 270px;
    }

    .amazon_bar em {
      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      left: 0;
      background: url(//i.wfcdn.de/5/amazon_bar_sprite_2.png) no-repeat;
    }

    a {
      padding: 0 5px 0 25px;
    }

    a:last-child {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 25px;
      position: relative;
      background: url(//i.wfcdn.de/5/amazon_bar_sprite_2.png) 0 -50px repeat-x;
      padding: 0 5px 0 25px;
      font-size: 13px;
      width: 270px;
    }

    a :last-child.favicon {
      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      left: 0;
      background: url(//i.wfcdn.de/5/amazon_bar_sprite_2.png) no-repeat;
      }

    .info {
      margin-top: 3px;
      color: #999;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
      -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }

    @keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="p_widget nointelliTXT">
    <amp-state id="items" src="https://winfuture-amp.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/products.json"></amp-state>
    <div class="title">Beliebte Smartwatches im Preisvergleich:</div>
    <div class="p_widget mt0 nointelliTXT">
      <div class="widget_tabs">
        <div class="tabs">
          <amp-list layout="fixed-height" height="145" src="https://winfuture-amp.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/products.json" [is-layout-container]="true" binding="no">
            <template type="amp-mustache">
              <div [class]="active ? 'tab_active' : ''" class="tab">
                <span role="button" tabindex="0" on="onclick:AMP.setState({name:'{{productName}}'}),onclick:AMP.setState({active:1})">{{productName}}</span>
              </div>
            </template>
          </amp-list>
        </div>

        <div class="tab_contents">
          <amp-list layout="fixed-height" height="85" src="https://winfuture-amp.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/first_ptoduct.json" [src]="items.items.filter(product => product.productName == name)" [is-layout-container]="true"
                  binding="no">
            <template type="amp-mustache">
              <div class="table">
                <div class="cell">
                  {{#productStore}}
                    <a href="{{website}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener" class="shop">
                      <span>
                        <amp-img class="favicon" width="16" height="16" src="{{icon}}" alt="icon"></amp-img>
                        {{websiteName}}
                      </span>
                      <span class="price">{{price}} €</span>
                    </a>
                  {{/productStore}}
                  {{^productStore}}
                  {{/productStore}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </template>
          </amp-list>
          <div class="info">Preise vom 04.06.22 12:34 Uhr, können jetzt anders sein.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question, was quite simple actually. I just needed to do some reading on css.

I used pseudo-class :focus. Simple to :hover and :active you can apply css on certain events that happen as the user interacts with your interface.

Applying ":focus" solved my problem:

```css
.tab:focus {
  background: #2578bb;
  width: 310px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```